# styling bootstrap carousel's caption below the slide

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap carousel (with angularjs, which shouldn't affect this question).

All is fine but I am having trouble styling the caption. If you take the carousel as-is, it will put some text about the slide on top of the image. I'd like to put the caption **below** the slide.

Sounds pretty simple - but I am having serious trouble with it. The caption is positioned absolute. Just changing bottom or top values doesn't solve my problem though: If I push the caption towards the end of the image, the text starts to disappear "below the fold", here's a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCwkP.jpg

So how can I push the text to appear below the slides? On top of them it is barely readable (not just because of the color), and the slides will be loaded dinamically so I can't choose a color and it will be fine I guess.

Comment: I'd love to know if you've figured out a solution.